# Applying Textures and Particles

Tags: texturing

I made some grass on a plane, when i applied the texture to the particles it also affected the plane... i am wondering if there is a way to apply the green texture to the particles only and a dirtbrown to the ground.
appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying a ground texture to the ground then going back to your particle system and assigning your particle’s material in the particle system drop down menus again. In that order it should work.

Comment: Thx dude, appreciate the help